# Attempts to use following-sibling to convert

Tags: xslt

I try to convert my old html by xslt-script to my new xml stucture.
I have a Problem to converting the folowing source to my needed xml structure.

Source

```
<p>
  <a class="DropDown">Example Text</a>
</p>
<div class="collapsed">
  <table>..</table>
  <p>..</p>
</div>
```

xml structure

```
<lq>
  <p>Example Text</p>
  <table>..</table>
  <p>..</p>
</lp>
```

I tried the following xls, but the div class="collapsed" is not adopted into the lp tag.

```
<xsl:template match="p/a[@class='DropDown']">
<lp>
  <p><xsl:apply-templates select="text()"/></p>
  <xsl:if test="/p/a/following-sibling::*[1][self::div]">
     <xsl:apply-templates select="*|text()"/>
  </xsl:if>
</lp>
</xsl:template>
```

Can anyone tell me what I did wrong ore where the mistake is?

Thanks much

Comment: Please always post a **complete** example - even if minimized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO, you want to do:

```
<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p[a/@class='DropDown']">
    <lp>
        <p>
            <xsl:value-of select="a"/>
        </p>
        <xsl:copy-of select="following-sibling::*[1][self::div]/node()"/>
    </lp>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="div[preceding-sibling::*[1][self::p/a/@class='DropDown']]"/>
```

As for your mistake:

1. You are testing the existence of *some* `p` that is the root element
   **and** contains an `a` whose following sibling is div. None of these are true in the given example;
2. `xsl:if` does not change the context: your `<xsl:apply-templates
   select="*|text()"/>` applies templates to the child nodes of the
   current `a`;
3. Presumably you don't want the `div` to appear again in the original place -
   so if you have another template to suppress it, you cannot use
   `<xsl:apply-templates>` to insert it at the place you do want it -
   at least not without using another mode.

Comment: Thanks for your help and for the good explanations.
It helped me a lot to realize my mistakes.
Your example does exactly what I wanted to do.